# scp does not display output when used with gnu parallel

Tags: zsh, scp, gnu-parallel

I have a short script that uses `scp` to copy files to a number of remote hosts (yes, I know about `rdist` and `rsync`; they both fail to work for a few of the hosts - that's not the point here; I'm only copying a few non-critical files anyway).

The meat of the script looks something like this:

```
for h in $HOSTS; do
    echo $h
    echo '----------------------------------------'
    scp -r $FILES ${h}:
    echo ''
done
```

Here is partial output from running this script:

```
protector
----------------------------------------
.bash_profile                                                                                                                100%  555     0.5KB/s   00:00    
.bashrc                                                                                                                      100% 2124     2.1KB/s   00:00    
.zshenv                                                                                                                      100%  561     0.6KB/s   00:00    
.zshrc                                                                                                                       100% 2354     2.3KB/s   00:00    
.shrc                                                                                                                        100% 1887     1.8KB/s   00:00    
.bash_logout                                                                                                                 100%   17     0.0KB/s   00:00    
.logout                                                                                                                      100%   64     0.1KB/s   00:00    
.zlogout                                                                                                                     100%   17     0.0KB/s   00:00    
.vimrc                                                                                                                       100%  717     0.7KB/s   00:00    

pup
----------------------------------------
.bash_profile                                                                                                                100%  555     0.5KB/s   00:00    
.bashrc                                                                                                                      100% 2124     2.1KB/s   00:00    
.zshenv                                                                                                                      100%  561     0.6KB/s   00:00    
.zshrc                                                                                                                       100% 2354     2.3KB/s   00:00    
.shrc                                                                                                                        100% 1887     1.8KB/s   00:00    
.bash_logout                                                                                                                 100%   17     0.0KB/s   00:00    
.logout                                                                                                                      100%   64     0.1KB/s   00:00    
.zlogout                                                                                                                     100%   17     0.0KB/s   00:00      
.vimrc                                                                                                                       100%  717     0.7KB/s   00:00
```

Since this script copies to hundreds of hosts, it takes a little while, so I decided to try to use [GNU Parallel](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/) to speed it up. Here is the revised version of the script utilizing `parallel` (please don't comment on the `echo` hack at the beginning, it's not relevant to the problem):

```
(for host in $(echo $HOSTS); do echo $host; done) | parallel "echo {}; echo '----------------------------------------' ; scp -r $FILES {}: ; echo ''"
```

The problem is that the output from using `scp` in this way looks like this:

```
pup
----------------------------------------

soils
----------------------------------------
```

Because the commands are running in parallel, the ordering is different, and parallel seems to complete much faster than a for loop of scps, but as you can see, there is no output to stdout from scp. I can't figure out why - output to stdout from echo is not being suppressed, for instance. When I try `scp -v` inside parallel, I get partial verbose output, but I don't get any of the usual size/time information.

Is there anybody who knows why scp output is getting suppressed?

Comment: It seems scp does not output unless it has a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trick `scp` into thinking it has a `tty` connected you can use `script`:

```
script -c 'scp foo server1:/bar/'
```

So to run that in with `parallel` you need something like:

```
parallel -j30 "echo {}; echo '----------------------------------------' ; script -c 'scp -r $FILES {}:' ; echo ''"   ::: $HOSTS
```

To learn more check out the intro videos (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1), the EXAMPLEs (n1_argument_appending">http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_xargs_*n1*_argument_appending), and the tutorial (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Comment: Brilliant. The examples in the tutorial were especially helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

for h in $(cat /tmp/servers);
do
    for f in $(cat /tmp/files);
    do
        echo $h
        echo '----------------------'
        parallel -vv "scp root@$h:$f /tmp"
    done
done
```

Take the -vv out to remove the verbose output. And of course modify it so that A) it uses your $HOSTS and $FILES variables, and B) it copies to the remote server rather than from.